# Be able to search by Subtitle

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search, uisearchbar

i set up the search so i could search by the title of my annotation but i want to search by the `subtitle` **as well !**

## Code:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    
    matchingItems = []
    guard let mapView = mapView,
        let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
    
    for item in self.mapView!.annotations    {
        let title = item.title!!
        
        
        if title.hasPrefix(searchBarText) && searchBarText != ""
        {
            matchingItems.append(item)
            
     }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

How can i implement it here in the code i have right now?

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Why are there so many `!` operators? Everyone means "crash here". Please read the appropriate sections of the Swift book and learn how to safely unwrap optionals.

Comment: Why do you check if `searchBarText != ""` inside the loop? Check it once outside the loop.

Comment: What issue are you having with subtitle? You already know how to check the title. The subtitle is the same.

Comment: yes but i don't know how to do both at the same time :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to search by subtitle too:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    guard let mapView = mapView,
        let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return  }

    matchingItems = self.mapView!.annotations.filter { annotation -> Bool in
        if annotation.title!.range(of: searchBarText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
            return true
        }

        if annotation.subtitle!.range(of: searchBarText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```